# In array of pointers to string, will all the strings be stored in contiguous memory locations?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, memory

When i implement an array of pointers to string , i know that the characters of a string literal will be stored in continuous memory locations,and the base address of each string will be stored in char pointers and also these pointers themselves will be stored in continuous memory locations , but will the strings be also stored in continuous memory locations,if yes ,explain the proper reason. for example - if base address of string "akshay" is 182 , so will the base address of next string "parag" be 189 ,if yes why so

```
char *names[]={ 
                "akshay",
                "parag",
                "raman",
                "srinivas"
                "gopal",
                "rajesh"
              };
```

Comment: No, because it is an array of pointers. *Those* will be stored contiguously. The string literals may or may not be consecutive, but they will probably be memory-aligned, that is, not 7 bytes away but 8 or 12, say.

Comment: yes i understand that pointers will be stored contiguously but will the strings also be stored continuously ?

Comment: what do you mean by memory alligned ?

Comment: I don't believe there is any requirement that they should be. Suppose the compiler is configured to re-use duplicate string literals, and two of your strings are the same. In that case they won't all be consectutive.

Comment: No, the strings can be anywhere in memory really. The compiler and linker will probably group them up, but there's no guarantees that `"akshay"` is directly followed by `"parag"` (for example).

Comment: Aligned to the natural size of the machine, at an address that is a multiple of 2, 4, 8 etc.

Comment: Is there a reason you're asking about this? Do you have another problem because of this? Of does a solution to another problem depend on this? If so, then perhaps you really should be asking about *that* problem instead (since this would then be worse than even [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: @WeatherVane: in my experience string literals generally aren't aligned to anything particular - there's no reason for it.

Comment: @MatteoItalia hmm, IDK. A test with (32-bit) MSVC of `char *ptr [] = {"A", "BB", "CCC" };` has pointer values `00848004`, `0084800C`, and `00848014`.

Comment: Note that if one of the names is `"ramachandra"` and another is `"chandra"`, it would be possible for the compiler to use one string literal for both names with the pointer for `"chandra"` starting at offset 4 from the pointer to `"ramachandra"`.  So, pointers to string literals needn't point to separate strings.

Comment: @WeatherVane: https://godbolt.org/g/NEjEEx 4, 9 E, both with gcc and clang, definitely not aligned to anything. Did you enable optimizations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Given your code

```
char *names[]={ 
    "akshay",
    "parag",
    "raman",
    "srinivas",
    "gopal",
    "rajesh"
};
```

there's no particular reason to expect the strings themselves to be stored in any particular relationship to each other.

One possible arrangement might be

```
names: 0x1002030: 0x100204c
       0x1002034: 0x100205a
       0x1002038: 0x100206c
       0x100203c: 0x1002073
       0x1002040: 0x1002054
       0x1002044: 0x1002060
       0x1002048:
       0x100204c: aksh
       0x1002050: ay
       0x1002054: gopa
       0x1002058: l pa
       0x100205c: rag
       0x1002060: raje
       0x1002064: sh
       0x1002068:
       0x100206c: rama
       0x1002070: n  s
       0x1002074: rini
       0x1002078: vas
```

P.S. For what it's worth, I tried your code under two different compilers, and the six strings *were* in fact stored contiguously.  I'm not surprised, but I also wouldn't have been surprised if they were stored in some other order.

Comment: It is not possible as string literals will be placed in the .rodata segment as they are Read Only

Comment: @P__J__ They *can* be stored in read-only memory, but it's not required that they be.  Anyway, in my example the `.rodata` segment begins at address `0x1002048`. :-)

Comment: @stevesummit so it is not always necessary that my strings will be stored in continuous memory locations and there is no particular rule for that ? right ???

Comment: @user9121710 Right.  Under many compilers, most of the time, they probably will be in order, but there's no guarantee whatsoever, so you'd never want to depend on it (and, realistically, it'd be unusual if you had some reason to depend on it).